# looping in a doubly linked list

Tags: linked-list

how to find a loop in a doubly linked list??how to eliminate the loops?

Comment: This is a common interview question. Here is a [nice explanation of the optimal solution](http://20bits.com/articles/interview-questions-loops-in-linked-lists/).

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the previous answer and comment to this problem, I see that they use the same approach that is used for detecting the loop in a singly-linked-list. But, there is a better way to solve this for a doubly linked-list.
Here is my approach- 
**Detecting the Loop**
In a Doubly linked-list ,while iterating we maintain a node - "last" representing the last visited node just before the current one. If there is a loop at any node then for that node the "previous" pointer( pointer to the previous node) will not same as "last" node.
On the other hand if there is no loop we will reach the end.

**Removing the Loop**
We simply update the 'next' of "last" to point to nothing ( NULL in C++).

Here is my C++ implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct node{
    int val;
    node *next=NULL,*prev=NULL;
    node(int x):val(x){}
};
bool detectAndRemoveLoopInDLL(node* head){
    node* last = NULL;
    while(head){
        if(last && last!=head->prev){
            cout<<"Loop found at: "<<head->val<<endl;
            last->next = NULL;
            return true;
        }
        last = head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout<<"No loop found"<<endl;
    return false;
}
int main() {
    node* head = new node(1);
    head->next = new node(2);
    head->next->next = new node(3); head->next->prev = head;
    head->next->next->next = new node(4); head->next->next->prev = head->next;
    head->next->next->next->next = new node(5); head->next->next->next->prev = head->next->next;
    head->next->next->next->next->next = new node(6); head->next->next->next->next->prev = head->next->next->next;
    head->next->next->next->next->next->next = new node(7); head->next->next->next->next->next->prev = head->next->next->next->next;
    head->next->next->next->next->next->next->next = new node(8); head->next->next->next->next->next->next->prev = head->next->next->next->next->next;
    //comment this for no loop
    head->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->next = head->next->next;
    head->next->next->next->next->next->next->next->prev = head->next->next->next->next->next->next;
    detectAndRemoveLoopInDLL(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider it as if it is a singly linked list and perform the following operations.

```
int detectloop(struct node *list)
{
  struct node  *slow_p = list, *fast_p = list;

  while(slow_p && fast_p &&
          fast_p->next )
  {
    slow_p = slow_p->next;
    fast_p  = fast_p->next->next;
    if (slow_p == fast_p)
    {
       printf("Found Loop");
       return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the above code we are using two pointers one is slow and another is fast, slow moves one step and fast moves two steps at a time.The time when they both meets we can say that the linked list is having loop otherwise not.

```
void removeLoop(struct node *loop_node, struct node *head)
{
   struct node *ptr1;
   struct node *ptr2;

   /* Set a pointer to the beging of the Linked List and
      move it one by one to find the first node which is
      part of the Linked List */
   ptr1 = head;
   while(1)
   {
     /* Now start a pointer from loop_node and check if it ever
       reaches ptr2 */
     ptr2 = loop_node;
     while(ptr2->next != loop_node && ptr2->next != ptr1)
     {
         ptr2 = ptr2->next;
     }

     /* If ptr2 reahced ptr1 then there is a loop. So break the
        loop */
     if(ptr2->next == ptr1)
        break;

     /* If ptr2 did't reach ptr1 then try the next node after ptr1 */
     else
       ptr1 = ptr1->next;
   }

   /* After the end of loop ptr2 is the last node of the loop. So
     make next of ptr2 as NULL */
   ptr2->next = NULL;
}
```

After detecting the loop we can use one loop and start it from the beginning and move the slow pointer at its as usual speed, when both the pointers meet the meeting point is the starting of the loop and we can break it.